# Userscript for posting formatted Bible content on SE

Tags: discussion, user-interface

I have posted the userscript that helps create markdown formatted bible quotes using the BibleGateway to the Stack Apps site. I have included links to the original from dancek and JackDouglas's fork as well as my own.

[Export BibleGatway page content in markdown format](https://stackapps.com/q/2992/3583).